# Hiding a div and all of its content on page load without flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is the only way to completely hide an element and its contents on page to add the following style to it?

```
display: none;
```

I noticed with any other technique during page load you see a slight flicker of the div's content. I have tried using jQuery show and hide functions but these do not seem to be good for page load.

Is there any other way besides this css style and just using css in general?

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: Yes, `display:none` hides completely the element. What you need? A monosylabic answer? Please, read this before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I feel bad adding this as an inline style to any element that I want completely hidden on page load. I was wondering if there were better ways using jQuery or JavaScript besides adding the same style to an element using .css().

Comment: @BlakeRivell you can add that to your stylesheet, there is no need for an inline style.

Comment: I must have worded my question incorrectly. I am aware of how to use css and inline styles. I was just wondering if there were any JavaScript/jQuery alternatives to fully hide an element.

Comment: @BlakeRivell : Why on earth do you want a JS solution for something that can be done with just a single line of CSS code? Also, if you can choose between CSS and JavaScript / jQuery to do the same thing, you should ALWAYS go for CSS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS create a class and add this in your div or whatever you want to hide it will hide without flashing.

```
.divonpageload {
                    height: 0px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    display: none;
                } 

<div id="firstpage">
<div id="secondpage" class="divonpageload">
<div id="preview">SHOW</div>    `
```

and create a jquery function:

```
 <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#preview").click(function () {
                  $("#secondpage").removeClass('divonpageload');
           });
       });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set whatever div you want to hide the following properties:

```
div {
  height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative css solution, but I am wondering if there are ways besides using css or is display: none; basically what everyone uses?

Comment: I mean, you can use jQuery to move the dev thousands of pixels of the page, but other than that, I just use `display:none;`, May I ask what you need an alternative for?

Comment: No reason, I regret even asking this question at this point. StackOverflow probably wasn't the right place. I simply just wanted to know what alternatives are out there besides using display: none; to make sure there was nothing I was missing.